# Have Karma suppress PhantomJS/Chrome status messages?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

I'm using PhantomJS for my Karma tests and the output is full of:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 198 of 307 (skipped 23) SUCCESS (0 secs / 11.566 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 199 of 307 (skipped 23) SUCCESS (0 secs / 11.574 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 200 of 307 (skipped 23) SUCCESS (0 secs / 11.582 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 201 of 307 (skipped 23) SUCCESS (0 secs / 11.591 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 202 of 307 (skipped 23) SUCCESS (0 secs / 11.599 secs)
```

Or when I use HeadlessChrome I see:

```
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 274 of 307 (skipped 31) SUCCESS (0 secs / 6.467 secs)
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 275 of 307 (skipped 31) SUCCESS (0 secs / 6.468 secs)
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6): Executed 276 of 307 (skipped 31) SUCCESS (0 secs / 6.468 secs)
```

But when I look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter examples, these don't exist. Am I missing something somewhere?

Guess I'm looking to see if I can just clean this output up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel silly. That's the default `process` plugin that Angular CLI does. Removed that and all good.